# GRUB mk-standalone usage

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-efi, secure-boot, hacking

I've managed to generate some custom version of `GRUB` using `mk-standalone`, with different module availability and the final efi files are in fact different in size, but when I check the `memdisk` content at boot, for example, for my light version without net support `(memdisk)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi` contains it with others unspecified anyway.

I'm using this shell code:

    `grub-mkstandalone --format x86_64-efi
                                     --install-modules="${VERSION_MODULES[@]}"`
                                   --modules="${VERSION_MODULES[@]}"
                                    --output /$version`

The other strange behaviour is that while `grub-mkstandalone --help` (or --usage) shows `--core-compression` as a possible option, when I try to use it, it prints out `(PROGRAM ERROR) Option should have been recognized!?`

Any ideas?